# pop element from list given index as user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment to pop a person on a looped list based on user input:

> Use a print statement to display, "Oops! It turns out one of your guests can't make it."
> Use the input() function to query the user for the index of the guest that can't make it. Since input() always returns a string, you'll need to use the int() function to convert the index provided to an integer.
> Use the pop() and the guest's index to remove the guest from the list. Since it's best practice to keep the user informed, display a confirmation message to the user including the guest's name. Note that pop() returns the value of the element deleted.

I can't figure out how to get it to pop based on input.

```
#First list of classmates

guests = ['ngqika', 'anissa', 'melina', 'robert', 'marcus', 'rob', 'keagon', 'william', 'jason', 'raven']

# guests list sorted and looped with title()
guests.sort()   
for guests in guests:
    print(guests.title())

message = ('\nOh no, one of your guests can not make it!')

print(message)

message2 = int(input('Please enter the index number of the guest to be deleted from the list: '))
```

I have tried `popped_guest = guests.pop()`, `popped_guest = guests.pop(message2)`, `popped_guest = guests.pop{message2}`.

Comment: Why were you not happy with what you have tried, in particular with `popped_guest = guests.pop(message2)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your option of

```
popped_guest = guests.pop(message2)
```

Works just fine. To see the result you need to print the list of guests after the execution of the pop() method:

```
    popped_guest = guests.pop(message2)
    print(f'\n{popped_guest.title()} has been removed from the list.')
    print('\nHere is the updated list of guests: ')
    print(guests)
```

You will see the guest removed from the list.

Comment: Dit it solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

message = ('\nOops! It turns outone of your guests can not make it!')
print(message)
index_num = int (input('Please enter the index number of the guest to be deleted from the list: '))

## popping the chosen guest

removed_guest = guests.pop(index_num).capitalize()
print("Confirmed!",removed_guest, "won't be able to